# Sprite teleports when moving mouse upwards Kaboom js

Tags: javascript, game-development, kaboom

For some reason in Kaboom JS when you have a sprite with a body like this:

```
const player = add([
  sprite("bean"),
  pos(center()),
  area(),
  scale(2),
  body(),
])
```

and you move the mouse quickly upwards the body teleports off screen.

Comment: You'll have to include the code that demonstrates the problem.